# Powershell script warning the filename directory name or volume syntax is incorrect

Tags: powershell, warnings

I have a pc inside a domain and we want to run an application with administrator priviledges i found this script from scackoverflow I deleted some parts

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRJJd.png)

But the thing is that when I run it it opens notepad but is gines me this warning window "the filename directory name or volume syntax is incorrect" can you please help?

I was expecting to open notepad

Comment: Please post the actual code into your question, properly formatted as a code block by using the `{}` button at the top, so people can see your code without needing to go to an external source.

Comment: Can you please share more details what your powershell script should do at the end, please? Do you wanna automate the launch of applications?

Answer (score 0):

The arguments you've shown don't make sense to be passed to notepad.exe. If you want to write the output of pwd to a text file, then open it, this is more appropriate:

```
pwd > c:\temp\output.txt
Start-Process -FilePath "c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe" -ArgumentList "c:\temp\output.txt"
```

If we assume notepad is the default text editor, even better:

```
pwd > c:\temp\output.txt
Invoke-Item c:\temp\output.txt
```